# leaflet map: remove road layer

Tags: r, leaflet, plot3d

I want to remove roads from my leaflet map in R. Is there a way to remove layers we want such as roads, lakes, state boundaries, etc.?

Sample code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(plot3D)
top = 45      # north lat
left = -110   # west long
right = -90   # east long
bottom =  32  # south lat

longitudes= seq(left,right, length.out = 3)
latitude=seq(bottom,top,length.out = 5)

 latlons_mesh=mesh(longitudes,latitude)

 longitude=as.vector(latlons_mesh$x)
 latitude=as.vector(latlons_mesh$y)

 mydata=data.frame(longitude=longitude,
                  latitude=latitude)

 leaflet(mydata)%>%fitBounds(right,bottom,left,top)%>%
    addTiles()%>%
    addMarkers()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roads and other features are part of the base `tile`, or you can call it 'background'.

By default the tiles are OSM's, but you can change with the `addTProviderTiles()` function, giving as argument one of the provider listed [here](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html).

For example a provider withour roads or boundaries is `Esri.WorldShadedRelief`:

```
leaflet(mydata) %>%
    fitBounds(right,bottom,left,top)%>%
    addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldShadedRelief') %>%
    addMarkers()
```